# ¿Cómo remover de un json la llave "nameValuePairs" en java SpringBoot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jsonobject, gson

Tengo el siguiente método que al recibir un xml en un String lo convierte a objetos de tipo **CitiMarketSSAEvent**

```
public CitiMarketSSAEvent convertXmlToObject(String xml){
    CitiMarketSSAEvent citiMarket = null;
    
    JAXBContext jaxbContext =     JAXBContext.newInstance(CitiMarketSSAEvent.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
    citiMarket = (CitiMarketSSAEvent) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    return citiMarket;
}
```

y después tengo el siguiente método que me convierte los objetos de esa clase en un json

```
public String convertObjectToJson(CitiMarketSSAEvent citiMarketObject) {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();
    gsonBuilder.disableHtmlEscaping();

    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    return gson.toJson(citiMarketObject, CitiMarketSSAEvent.class);
}
```

y me pinta el json de la siguiente manera

```html
{
    "header":{
        "name": "transactionCount",
        "version": "2.0",
        "code": "1530",
        "country": "MX",
        "domain": "counts",
        "time": "2018-10-11 11:20:34.323 GMT",
    },
    "body":{
        "INPUNT": "I",
        "MESSAGE_01": "RSTW",
        "MESSAGE_02": "MNXTYP",
        "MESSAGE_03": "RSTWERDCV",
        "SEND_TIME": "20-NOV-2011 04:53:04 p.m.",
        "RCV_ID": "ABGRCV",
        "FORMAT0_MONTO": "200,000,300.00",
        "FORMATO_MONEDA": "USD",
        "CONTROL_01": "MSG1RCVSND",
        "CONTROL_02": "MSG2RCVSND",
        "CONTROL_03": "MSG3RCVSND",
    }
}
```

pero quiero agregar la llave "event"  al json de tal manera que me quede algo como esto:

```html
{
 "event":{
    "header":{
        "name": "transactionCount",
        "version": "2.0",
        "code": "1530",
        "country": "MX",
        "domain": "counts",
        "time": "2018-10-11 11:20:34.323 GMT",
    },
    "body":{
        "INPUNT": "I",
        "MESSAGE_01": "RSTW",
        "MESSAGE_02": "MNXTYP",
        "MESSAGE_03": "RSTWERDCV",
        "SEND_TIME": "20-NOV-2011 04:53:04 p.m.",
        "RCV_ID": "ABGRCV",
        "FORMAT0_MONTO": "200,000,300.00",
        "FORMATO_MONEDA": "USD",
        "CONTROL_01": "MSG1RCVSND",
        "CONTROL_02": "MSG2RCVSND",
        "CONTROL_03": "MSG3RCVSND",
    }
  }
}
```

y entonces modifiqué mi metodo de la siguiente manera

```
    public String convertObjectToJson(CitiMarketSSAEvent citiMarketObject) {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();
        gsonBuilder.disableHtmlEscaping();
        
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("event",citiMarketObject);
        
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        return gson.toJson(jsonObj, JSONObject.class);                                            
  }
```

y me arroja el json pero se le agrego la llave "nameValuePairs" como se le puede quitar? o como mas puedo hacerle para solo agregar la llave "event"

```
 {
    "nameValuePairs":{
        "event":{
            "header":{
                "name": "transactionCount",
                "version": "2.0",
                "code": "1530",
                "country": "MX",
                "domain": "counts",
                "time": "2018-10-11 11:20:34.323 GMT",
            },
            "body":{
                "INPUNT": "I",
                "MESSAGE_01": "RSTW",
                "MESSAGE_02": "MNXTYP",
                "MESSAGE_03": "RSTWERDCV",
                "SEND_TIME": "20-NOV-2011 04:53:04 p.m.",
                "RCV_ID": "ABGRCV",
                "FORMAT0_MONTO": "200,000,300.00",
                "FORMATO_MONEDA": "USD",
                "CONTROL_01": "MSG1RCVSND",
                "CONTROL_02": "MSG2RCVSND",
                "CONTROL_03": "MSG3RCVSND",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr tu objetivo en vez de usar `org.json.JSONObject` podrías probar con `com.google.gson.JsonObject` de la libreria [gson](/questions/tagged/gson)
Entonces el código quedaría así:

```
...
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
jsonObject.add("event", gson.toJsonTree(citiMarketObject));
return jsonObject;
```